# Path to executable of MyPy plugin for PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, mypy

I am trying to use the [MyPy Plugin for Pycharm by Leinardi](https://github.com/leinardi/mypy-pycharm).
I installed it via the [official steps](https://github.com/leinardi/mypy-pycharm#installation-steps).
In the settings, I am able to see Mypy, but "Path to Mypy exectuable:" is not set (there is only "Auto-detected:").

**What do I put into "Path to Mypy exectuable:" - where is the Mypy exectuable installed to by default?**

I am using a conda environment - I don't know if this is important.
Also, when pressing "Test", I get the error, you can see below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Mac or Windows:

```
where mypy
```

If you're on Linux:

```
which mypy
```

Then just copy and paste one of the outputs into the location in PyCharm.

Edit:

Based on your comment, which says that using a command above indicates that no executable could be found, I suggest looking at your IDE and system. It may be that MyPy is not installed:

[image: mypy not installed]

If you don't see the pop up like in the image above, you can use steps here for Anaconda: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/mypy or uninstall the plugin and re-install it, allowing you to see the PyCharm popup.

Then you should be able to see it do its magic.

[image: mypy installed]

Comment: I had tried this: I am just told that no file under this name could be found.

Comment: @Make42 Thanks, I updated my answer. It may or may not help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same case as you and could solve the problem after I have installed mypy not only as a plugin but also with pip install in my virtual environment.